# Buscador ajax duplica la busqueda

Tags: ajax

estoy trabajando en un buscador con ajax, pero resulta que al buscar se me duplica la interfaz asi como lo muestra la imagen, ya e buscado pero no e podido, de antemano muchas gracias. [image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

```
`      $('#buscar_usuario').on('keyup', function() {
        var query = $(this).val();
        $.ajax({
            url:"{{ route('clientes.index') }}",
            type: 'GET',
            data: {query: query},
            success: function(data){
                $('#lista_usuarios').html(data);
            }      
        });
    });
```

Comment: A ciegas es dificil ayudar, pero me parece claro que el elemento con el id #lista_usarios engloba al elemento con el id #buscar_usuario, y de ahí que se te repita. Pon el html en la pregunta si necesitas mejor ayuda, pero deberias entender por donde van los tiros con esto que digo.

Comment: estas pidiendo `clientes.index` y dibujandolo en `#lista_usuarios` si `clientes.index` incluye el formulario, eso tambien se dibuja. fijate si no es algo tipo `clientes.search` o `clientes.results` o `clientes.list`